# Changing menu <li> to <dd> with wp_nav_menu

Tags: php, wordpress

I created a theme in HTML using Zurb Foundation and then integrated it into a WordPress theme.

The primary nav section in my theme, in its most basic form is:

```
<dl>
  <dd></dd>
  <dd></dd>
  <dd></dd>
</dl>
```

I configured wordpress's menu call as such:

```
wp_nav_menu( array(
    'theme_location' => 'primary',
    'menu'            => '',
    'container'       => '',
    'container_class' => '',
    'container_id'    => '',
    'menu_class'      => 'menu',
    'menu_id'         => '',
    'echo'            => true,
    'fallback_cb'     => 'wp_page_menu',
    'before'          => '',
    'after'           => '',
    'link_before'     => '',
    'link_after'      => '',
    'items_wrap'      => '<dl id="tabnav" class="sub-nav">%3$s</dl>',
    'depth'           => 0,
    'walker'          => '') );
```

But in order to change the wrapping `<li>` that wordpress puts out to a `<dd>` I would need to write a custom walker.

I looked through some custom walkers and can see parts of the logic, but is creating a class every time I want to use custom html for a menu the only/most efficient way to go about it?

Comment: Did you use `?` anywhere ?

Answer (score 0):

[digwp](http://digwp.com/) provides an easier approach than the walker

create a function that builds the menu from scratch.

in your functions.php

```
// custom menu example @ http://digwp.com/2011/11/html-formatting-custom-menus/
function clean_custom_menus() {
    $menu_name = 'nav-primary'; // specify custom menu slug
    if (($locations = get_nav_menu_locations()) && isset($locations[$menu_name])) {
        $menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object($locations[$menu_name]);
        $menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items($menu->term_id);

        $menu_list = '<dl>' ."\n";
        foreach ((array) $menu_items as $key => $menu_item) {
            $title = $menu_item->title;
            $url = $menu_item->url;
            $menu_list .= "\t\t\t\t\t". '<dd><a href="'. $url .'">'. $title .'</a></dd>' ."\n";
        }
        $menu_list .= "\t\t\t". '</dl>' ."\n";
    } else {
        // $menu_list = '<!-- no list defined -->';
    }
    echo $menu_list;
}
```

and to call it in your theme:

```
<?php if (function_exists(clean_custom_menus())) clean_custom_menus(); ?>
```

so you would have to edit the `$menu_name` to your menu slug.

here's the [source](http://digwp.com/2011/11/html-formatting-custom-menus/)